# Configure IPTables on KVM host to block guest bridge traffic

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, redhat, kvm-virtualization

I am working on a thesis research project, and I am having some difficulty figuring out how to get `iptables` (running on the KVM host) to block traffic (or rather, manipulate traffic) destined for a *BRIDGED* KVM guest.  I am unable to get the `iptables` entries (pasted below) to block traffic to and from the VM's.

Effectively, I would like my host system to act as a firewall for those guest VM's, and for the time being, I would like to test this capability by simply dropping all packets that is destined for a specific VM.  In the not-so-distant future, I would also like to implement more granular controls, and even have a proxy involved.  Again, this should happen entirely at the HOST level, and *not* at the GUEST level.

I am running CentOS 6, and based on another question that I wrote: [Use one NIC to create multiple interfaces for Linux KVM](https://serverfault.com/questions/456572/use-one-nic-to-create-multiple-interfaces-for-linux-kvm), I have the following interfaces configured:

```
eth0
br0
tap0
```

Below is my network setup scripts for each interface:

`eth0`'s Configuation:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="none"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="<<UUID-HERE>>"
HWADDR=<<MAC-ADDR-HERE>>
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
BRIDGE="br0"
```

`br0`'s Configuration:

```
DEVICE="br0"
TYPE="Bridge"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DELAY=0
```

`tap0`'s Configuration:

```
DEVICE="tap0"
TYPE="Tap"
BRIDGE="br0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

I have a CentOS 6 VM running and it is configured to utilize the `tap0` bridged interface.  Networking on the VM is working properly. No other changes to the host system were made.

Below are the non-functioning `iptables` rules that I added to the `FORWARD` chain (*it is worth noting that I am not a huge expert on `iptables` yet*).

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i any -o tap0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i tap0 -o any -j DROP
```

After running the commands, the `FORWARD` table looks like this:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  tap0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    tap0    anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Unfortunately, this does not block the traffic.  I don't understand why this would not work.

**UPDATE: 11/25/2014:** It's been a while since I last updated this.  As it turns out, `iptables` has the `physdev` plugin, which is actually what I successfully use in my research and is more flexible then `ebtables`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you understand the networking basics involved here. A bridge is a switch and operates at Layer 2. Your `iptables` rules apply to Layer 3 and will not be passed at this level.

Look into `ebtables` and specify Layer 2 rules there - or - disable the use of bridges altogether and move to a routed setup in which all traffic is passed through the host at Layer 3. Not sure if the latter option is possible using Libvirt/KVM.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  How would using `ebtables` compare to using `PHYSDEV` as an option in `iptables`?

Comment: Additionally, because this is operating at level 2, how would one perform proxy filtering for that VM?

Comment: `ebtables` looks like the solution for my initial problem, and is thus the answer to this question.

Comment: Just to provide an update: `physdev` in `iptables` provides much of the functionality that I require, as you can examine the inbound and outbound to an interface on a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables`

it will enable netfilter on bridges and then you can set up iptables rules on the FORWARD chain to affect packets going to/from the virtual machines via the bridge interface.

To make it permanent on reboot:

edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1`

https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf

Although the wiki says it's not desirable to do this, I have been doing this for years.  It allows me to set up blacklists and other iptables/ipset rules on the FORWARD chain that work globally for all VMs. It works just fine on moderately loaded servers.